# Una respuesta muy corta y de baja calidad, ¿se considera una respuesta o un comentario?

Tags: discusión

Mi duda surge de la pregunta siguiente: [Optimizar consulta SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8816/optimizar-consulta-sql/), donde el usuario pide si hay manera de mejorar el rendimiento de su consulta SQL.

Una de las respuestas es la siguiente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/29003/18951, donde el usuario, con una frase minimalista sin detalles, propone una solución al problema.

Como parece que ha sido borrado la respuesta entre tanto, aquí la pongo para referencia:

> porque no haces un stored procedure? la primera vez tardara un poco pero si se consulta de nuevo deberia tenerla ya en memoria...

En mi opinión, la respuesta no es útil porque le falta proveer código o detalles prácticos, y además, yo pienso que su propuesta es incorrecta.

Pero, luego noté que se le dejó el siguiente comentario bajo su respuesta:

> **Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta**. En cuanto tengas suficiente reputación podrás comentar en cualquier publicación. Mejor es proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta.

Estoy de acuerdo que la respuesta es de muy baja calidad, y puede que algunos opinen que merece un voto negativo ¿pero quiere decir eso que ni siquiera se considera una respuesta, y que debería ser reportado como tal?

Cuando le pregunté al que dejó el comentario al respecto, me contestó:

> conociendo cómo va el sitio, para considerarse respuesta debería contener el procedimiento almacenado y/o código y/o una explicación con mayores detalles. Como no veo alguno de los elementos mencionados, **esta respuesta es un comentario**.

Ahora bien, respeto el hecho que este usuario lleva tiempo usando el sitio, y conoce mejor el funcionamiento de las cosas que yo. Yo aún soy tan solo un novato aquí. Pero me interesa verificar cuál es el consenso de la comunidad, ya que no hallé ninguna información clara en meta al respecto.

La única información que tengo es la que proviene de meta.stackexchange aquí: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), que, de paso, usa una gráfica interesante con manzanas para ilustrar el punto (vale la pena echarle un vistazo). Pero como he estado aprendiendo, SOes no necesariamente sigue las mismas normas que los demás sitios de la misma familia. Por eso prefiero plantear la pregunta aquí para recibir guía e iluminación.

Así que, nuevamente, mi pregunta es: si una respuesta es demasiado corta, sin detalles pertinentes, ¿se considera una respuesta o un comentario? Y por extensión, ¿se debería reportar como *no es una respuesta*?

Comment: Opino igual: sin juzgar si es buena, creo que **es** una respuesta, y no hubiese recomendado borrar ni llevar a comentario, probablemente también siguiendo la lógica de SO. Pero veo que [un usuario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17591) revisó como que estaba bien, [la cola de baja calidad](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17592) fue 4 a 1, y un moderador lo [movió a comentario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8816/optimizar-consulta-sql/29003#comment46884_8816).. También me interesa mucho ver qué opina la comunidad.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/958/227)

Comment: @sstan Ahora hay una respuesta oficial al respecto